# How can I hide a TD tag using inline JavaScript or CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, visibility

How can I hide a `<td>` tag using JavaScript or inline CSS?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

What do you expect to happen in it's place? The table can't reflow to fill the space left - this seems like a recipe for buggy browser responses.

Think about hiding the contents of the td, not the td itself.

Comment: However, there is undesired space between hidden cells even when width it set to 0.

Answer (score 41):

```
.hide{

visibility: hidden

}

<td class="hide"/>
```

**Edit-**
Just for you

The difference between display and visibility is this.

**"display":** has many properties or values, but the ones you're focused on are "none" and "block". "none" is like a hide value, and "block" is like show. If you use the "none" value you will **totally** hide what ever html tag you have applied this css style. If you use "block" you will see the html tag and it's content. very simple.

**"visibility":** has many values, but we want to know more about the "hidden" and "visible" values. "hidden" will work in the same way as the "block" value for display, but this will hide tag and it's content, but it will not hide the phisical space of that tag. For example, if you have a couple of text lines, then and image (picture) and then a table with three columns and two rows with icons and text. Now if you apply the visibility css with the hidden value to the image, the image will disappear but the space the image was using will remaing in it's place, in other words, you will end with a big space (hole) between the text and the table. Now if you use the "visible" value your target tag and it's elements will be visible again.

Comment: what about display:none;  will that work? (cross browser etc).

Comment: visibile:hidden- hides the element, but saves the space it occupies; 

display:none -doesn't just hide the element, it also gets rid of the space

Answer (score 9):

Same way you'd hide anything: `visibility: hidden;`

Comment: what about display:none;  will that work? (cross browser etc).

Comment: display:none is in my experience what you actually want 95% of the time

Comment: Visibility hides the element without altering the flow of the document and so should avoid the sort of problems edeverett is worried about.

Comment: @simon  yeah, that probably is the case but I'd still test it heavily in IE, my spider-sense is warning me that it may cause problems. I've had too many bad experiences with IE and tables.

Comment: Well, that's good advice for everything - always assume IE will mess it up and you can't go far wrong!

Answer (score 8):

Everything is possible (or almost) with css, just use:

```
display: none; //to hide

display: table-cell //to show
```

Answer (score 6):

```
<td style = "display:none" >
<p> Content display none </p>
</td>
```

or

```
<td style="visibility:hidden"> Your content is hidden </td>
```

Notice that: 2 those ways are differnce. You should try it to check the result.

Answer (score 4):

If you have more than this in javascript consider some javascript library, e.g. [jquery](http://jquery.com) which takes away a little speed, but gives you more readable code.

Your question's code via [jquery](http://jquery.com):

```
$("td").hide();
```

Of course there are other javascript libraries out there, as [this comparison on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_JavaScript_frameworks) shows.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply hide the `<td>` tag content by just including a style attribute: `style = "display:none"`

For e.g

```
<td style = "display:none" >
<p> I'm invisible </p>
</td>
```

Answer (score 1):

We can hide the content inside a  by using the following inline css:

```
<div style="visibility:hidden"></div>
```

for example:

```
<td><div style="visibility:hidden">Your Content Goes Here:</div></td>
```