# How do I hide a table column in print mode?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

How do I hide an entire table column in printing mode (using JS javascript:print())?

Because I'm using Bootstrap I tried its .hidden-print class to hide the last column (Operation column) in printing mode:

```
<table class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>No</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th class="hidden-print">Operation</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>John Smith</td>
      <td class="hidden-print">
        <a href="edit.php" role="button" class="btn">Edit</a>
        <a href="delete.php" role="button" class="btn">Delete</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Neo</td>
      <td class="hidden-print">
        <a href="edit.php" role="button" class="btn">Edit</a>
        <a href="delete.php" role="button" class="btn">Delete</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <-- continued -->
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

but it's only hide the column's content, displaying a column without content, when I need is it also hides TH and TD tags.

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
table,th,td {
  border: 1px solid;
  text-align: center;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}
@media print {
  table,th,td {
    border: 0px
  }
  button {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<table class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>No</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th class="hidden-print">Operation</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>John Smith</td>
      <td class="hidden-print">
        <a href="edit.php" role="button" class="btn">Edit</a>
        <a href="delete.php" role="button" class="btn">Delete</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Neo</td>
      <td class="hidden-print">
        <a href="edit.php" role="button" class="btn">Edit</a>
        <a href="delete.php" role="button" class="btn">Delete</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<button onclick="window.print();">Print</button>
```

Comment: This is a good solution, but it's not working for me, as the content of the table cells are being centered, which is not my intention. Thanks anyway.

Comment: you can change " text-align: left; "

Answer (score 0):

There are issues with adding `display: none;` (which is what `.hidden-print` does) to table rows and cells because removing them from the document flow could very easily mess up the table formatting ([see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/916528/how-can-i-hide-a-td-tag-using-inline-javascript-or-css)).

What about using `visibility: hidden;` instead?

In your case, you could try this, if you wanted to always target the last column:

```
@media print {
  th:last-child, td:last-child {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, this was the same as my original code: hide content only, the border etc were still there.

Comment: Weird, this works for me, even with a background and border set on `<tr>` and `<td>` elements. It won't work for adjusting a border around the entire table, though.